# In the mgcv ::bam function in R, how can I constrain a two dimensional smooth to be monotonically increasing in both dimensions for large data?

Tags: generalized-additive-model, poisson-regression, large-data, mgcv, constrained-regression

I have a large dataset (1.3M rows) where I want to ensure that both Age and Duration increase monotonically for each by factor level (Male, Female). Here is the setup of the model:

```r
m1 <- bam(Deaths ~ te(Duration, Age, k = c(8, 8), by = Sex) + 
                   offset(log(Exposure)), nthreads = 2, 
          discrete = TRUE, data = data, family = poisson)
```

I have tried the `scam` package with double monotonic increasing constraints but that seems to never finish or provide an error, probably because the dataset is too large. I also tried fiddling with `mgcv::pcls()` as the examples provided by Simon in the help page suggest monotonic constraints could be incorporated but, as no examples are provided for two-dimensional tensor product smooths, I was unable to get it to work.

I am still open to using the scam package if there are any ways to make it more efficient/work. I tried a few things already like reducing k a bit (e.g. to c(4,4)), fixing the smoothing parameters to sp=c(1,1) and fiddling with the optimizer without any success. Here was exactly what I tried:

```r
m2 <- scam(Deaths ~ s(Duration, Age, k = c(4, 4), bs = 'tedmi', 
           by = Sex) + offset(log(Exposure)), data = data, 
           family = poisson)
```

Would appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: I don't think it is possible with `bam()`. You could try the *cgam* package, which is meant to be a lot faster than *scam* but I don't know how well it with scale with that much data